# Is the ceramic insulator on old espresso machine heating elements absolutely necessary?

Tags: insulator

I've spent several hours trying to understand if these ceramic insulators are really necessary on some heating element end pins.  There are some terminal pins where they are absolutely needed, usually on the older heating elements, where they actually supporting and provided separation from the washers/nut/terminal fitting to the baseplate. But many of the new designs have brazed on washers or terminal connectors to the end pin. In that case I don't understand these ceramic insulators and just wonder if some manufactures just install them because they used to be always installed (necessarily) in the old designs. Everything I've read (so far) is that in many electrical applications ceramic insulators seem to just provide separation/support to keep conductors away from each other. Can anyone show me information online (or tell me with references on why provided) on why these ceramic insulators might be needed when not used for separation or support of fastening components. thank you! Photo 1 shows image of old element where the ceramic insulators are needed for support of the washer, nut, terminal. Photo 2 shows element where the terminal connectors are brazed to the element end pins. (i'm thinking ceramic insulators not really needed in this case) Photo 3 shows photo of teflon tube being inserted to replace broken off ceramic insulators. (really needed??)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If those spacers are loading bearing you might need them to prevent them from being forced deeper into the heating element. Difficult to say though without taking the case off.

Comment: the manufacturer most likely asked the same question